# SSL certificate prob: self signed certificate

Tags: ssl, curl, ssl-certificate, libcurl

I use this HTTP client to connect to my server 
code :

```
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  CURLcode res;
  char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];

  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");

  /* provide a buffer to store errors in */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);

  /* set the error buffer as empty before performing a request */
  errbuf[0] = 0;

  /* perform the request */
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

  /* if the request did not complete correctly, show the error
  information. if no detailed error information was written to errbuf
  show the more generic information from curl_easy_strerror instead.
  */
  if(res != CURLE_OK) {
    size_t len = strlen(errbuf);
    fprintf(stderr, "\nlibcurl: (%d) ", res);
    if(len)
      fprintf(stderr, "%s%s", errbuf,
              ((errbuf[len - 1] != '\n') ? "\n" : ""));
    else
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
  }
}
```

but the connexion failed and I got this error msg :

> - SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
>
> libcurl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate

the certification is under /etc/ssl folder and it is a valid certification

how to proceed to solve this issue !

Comment: cUrl stops on invalid certifcates. On the command line there's the `-k` switch to let it continue in those cases, you should just find the corresponding API to turn that switch on in the code.

Comment: `http://example.com` implies you're not using HTTPS at all... ?

Comment: @watery I believe the API in question is [CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html). If this option is set to `0` then libcurl does not verify that the SSL cert was signed by a trusted authority.